# What is the relation between the bitcoin address and the corresponding private key?

Tags: address

Just wondering how do get the address given that we store only a public key? What is the relation between them? Is address a simple hash of private key? If yes, what hashing algorithm is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Bitcoin address is a hash of the public key. The [Bitcoin wiki explains](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) the exact (complicated) procedure in great detail. In brief, it involves hashing the public key and includes a checksum. The private key and public key are [mathematically related](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/ECDSA).

- If you have the private key, you can easily calculate the public key and address.
- If you have the public key, you can easily calculate the address, but not the private key.
- If you have the address, you cannot calculate either key.